# Unable to save entities with crud repo inside setUp method of class, annotated with @SpringBootTest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test, java-17

Im trying to run integrating testing, having created before some fixtures and saved them inside @BeforeEach. Annotation @DataJpaTest allows me to do this, but I need also @SpringBootTest, because I need ApplicationContext and many beans. Earlier in spring boot 2.3.5 I could use these two annotations at the same time, but now **(spring boot 2.6.3, java 17, springCloudVersion 2021.0.0, gradle 7.3.3)**  it cause error "multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith" and I must leave only @SpringBootTest, but without @DataJpaTest my fixtures don't save inside @BeforeEach method . How can I resolve this issues?

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = TestConfigurations.Initializer.class,
        classes = {MainAppClass.class, TestConfigurations.class}
)
public class SomeTest {

    @Autowired
    protected SomeCrudRepo someCrudRepo;

    @Nested
    class SomeNestedTest {

        @BeforeEach
        void setUp() {
            List<Entity> entities = Fixtures.SOME_ENTITIES();
            someCrudRepo.saveAll(entities); // doesn't save
        }
........
```

Comment: Those annotations have always been mutually exclusive and actually "worked together" by accident. Your test needs to have a transaction without a transaction nothing will be saved. Annotate your test with `@Transactional`.

Comment: Did this with test method and with setUp() method, nothing

Comment: How do you know it doesn't save? Data will be rolledback after the test method, so nothing will be persisted after the test run.

Comment: 1. via debug
2. crushed tests (they work earlier)

Comment: debug? I don't get that? There is nothing in the database as your test executes in a transaction, so stopping the execution and going to your database to check wont help as it doesn't really commit. Your main test class (next to `@SpringBootTest` should have `@Transactional` not the individual test methods). The `@DataJpaTest` is annotated with `@Transactional` whilst `@SpringBootTest` isn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the full application, yes, combining `@SpringBootTest` with `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase` is an appropriate solution, as it does just that.

It is also mentioned in [the documentation of @DataJpaTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/jdbc/AutoConfigureTestDatabase.html):

> Si desea cargar la configuración completa de su aplicación, pero usa
> una base de datos integrada, debe considerar @SpringBootTest combinado
> con @AutoConfigureTestDatabase en lugar de esta anotación.

Although the spring framework promotes the approach you are taking, [m-deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) proposal is a good one.

Annotate your Test class with `@Transactional` to get the want behavior for each test method.

good coding! ¯_(ツ)_/¯